# Google api batch update giving HTTP 400 error. Python

Tags: python, api, documentation, google-docs-api

The google api for docs is giving me HTTP 400 error.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1Z2rAi7CJINAwxzizOsIw0_UB1iguHaduIDBV5cOZ4iQ:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[0].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines.">
```

i have searched all over the place to find it. it is to insert in a blank document. it says to add a new paragraph but i dont know how to.

```py
title = 'My Document'
text1 = "hi this is the first one"
text2 = "hi this is the first one"
text3 = "hi this is the first one"
body = {


        'title': title

    }
    requests = [
        {
            'insertText': {
                'location': {
                    'index': 0,
                },
                'text': text1
            }
        }
    ]




doc = service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(
        doc.get('title')))
docid = doc.get('documentId')
print(docid)
result = service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=docid, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

the compelte error message is this:

> ```
> "E:/Python/News Uploader to Google Driver/venv/Scripts/quickstart.py"
> Created document with title: My Document
> 1Z2rAi7CJINAwxzizOsIw0_UB1iguHaduIDBV5cOZ4iQ Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "E:/Python/News Uploader to Google
> Driver/venv/Scripts/quickstart.py", line 76, in <module>
>     main()   File "E:/Python/News Uploader to Google Driver/venv/Scripts/quickstart.py", line 70, in main
>     result = service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=docid, body={'requests': requests}).execute()   File "E:\Python\News Uploader
> to Google Driver\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py",
> line 130, in positional_wrapper
>     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "E:\Python\News Uploader to Google Driver\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line
> 856, in execute
>     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1Z2rAi7CJINAwxzizOsIw0_UB1iguHaduIDBV5cOZ4iQ:batchUpdate?alt=json
> returned "Invalid requests[0].insertText: The insertion index must be
> inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new
> paragraphs by inserting newlines.">
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your request you should specify the location index as 1, since Google API is indexed from 1

```
requests = [
        {
            'insertText': {
                'location': {
                    'index': 1,
                },
                'text': text1
            }
        }
    ]
```